# Localização em segundo plano android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

---------- Esse é o meu serviço

```
public class LocationMonitoringService extends Service implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = LocationMonitoringService.class.getSimpleName();
GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();


public static final String ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST = LocationMonitoringService.class.getName() + "LocationBroadcast";
public static final String EXTRA_LATITUDE = "extra_latitude";
public static final String EXTRA_LONGITUDE = "extra_longitude";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.LOCATION_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.FASTEST_LOCATION_INTERVAL);


    int priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY; //by default
    //PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY, PRIORITY_LOW_POWER, PRIORITY_NO_POWER are the other priority modes


    mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);
    mLocationClient.connect();

    //Make it stick to the notification panel so it is less prone to get cancelled by the Operating System.
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

/*
 * LOCATION CALLBACKS
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

        Log.d(TAG, "== Error On onConnected() Permission not granted");
        //Permission not granted by user so cancel the further execution.

        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    Log.d(TAG, "Connected to Google API");
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
 * location client drops because of an error.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection suspended");
}

//to get the location change
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location changed");


    if (location != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "== location != null");

        //Send result to activities
        sendMessageToUI(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

    }
}

private void sendMessageToUI(String lat, String lng) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Sending info... latitude: "+ lat + " | longitude: " + lng);

    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LATITUDE, lat);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LONGITUDE, lng);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to connect to Google API");

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //Stop location sharing service to app server.........

    stopService(new Intent(this, LocationMonitoringService.class));
    Log.d(TAG, "OnDestroy");
    //Ends................................................
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

---------- esse é o meu manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="sysystem.panictrackermap">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.something.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.something.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.something.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_maps"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_maps"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name=".services.ServiceLocationStarter">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".services.LocationMonitoringService" />

    <receiver android:name=".services.BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".firebase.CDCMessasingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".firebase.CDCInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

---

A localização está vindo legal em primeiro plano porem em segundo plano ela para e eu gostaria que ela viece para fazer uma especie de localizador pessoal

OBS(quando estava em aplicativos separados ela trazia, porem quando juntei os app ela parou de rodar em segundo plano...

Comment: Lendo os artigos da nova versão (android 8.0) descobri que ele não ira mais atualizar a localização em tempo real pela **FusedLocationApi** agora que fiquei mais perdido que sego em tiroteio.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema!
acrecentei o codigo na MainActivity para a chamada do serviço com api 26 android O (OREO)

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

        MainActivity.this.startForegroundService(new Intent(this, LocationMonitoringService.class));
    }else{
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), LocationMonitoringService.class));
    }
```

com anotação @TargetApi(26);

Desta forma o serviço não é destruido em segundo plano...